# Degree of an isogeny of abelian varieties related to the rank of its kernel

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $\alpha:X\rightarrow Y$ be an isogeny between two abelian varieties over a field $k$, of degree $d$ and separable degree $d_s$. We may assume $k$ to be algebraically closed if necessary.

In Mumford's book "Abelian varieties" (application $3$ in chapter $6$), it is recalled that the cardinality of $\alpha^{-1}\{y\}$ is $d_s$ for almost all points $y\in Y$. Because each of these fibers is just a translate of $\ker(\alpha)$, it follows that the rank of $\ker(\alpha)$, seen as a finite group-scheme over $k$, is $d_s$.

In Moonen's notes on abelian varieties (more precisely [here](https://www.math.ru.nl/~bmoonen/BookAV/Isogs.pdf) at the top of page $2$), using the finite flatness of $\alpha$ we know that $\alpha_{\star}\mathcal O_X$ is a locally free $\mathcal O_Y$-module of finite rank (ref. Mumford's GIT, chapter $0$ section $5$). This rank can be computed at the generic point of $Y$ and at the closed point $0\in Y$, which gives the equalities $d = \operatorname{rank}_{\mathcal O_Y}(\alpha_{\star}\mathcal O_X)=\operatorname{rank}(\ker \alpha)$.

Both claims seem to enter into contradiction, as we shouldn't have $d=d_s$ in general as far as I understand. Would somebody see which statement is false and why ?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but one way out of this issue would be if the rank of $\ker(\alpha)$ was not necessarily equal to it's cardinality. What happens when you take something like $k=\Bbb F_p(t)$, $Y=\operatorname{Spec} k$, and $X=\operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(x^p-t)$, for instance?

Comment: @KReiser I see, this may indeed be the source of my confusion. I was assuming that rank and cardinality would agree, but it may not. Mumford refers in fact to the cardinality of the kernel, whereas Moonen refers to the rank. Thank you very much, the picture is now clearer for me